# failed Connection closed before receiving a handshake response sipml5

Tags: javascript, websocket, sipml5

I have an application that connect to freepbx server. The application can't connect to websocket on my freepbx server. the error is : 'failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response sipml5'
This case just happened sometime. When more than 10 minutes, the server can connect again.
How to fix it? or can i check what is the problem?